# topology simple bounded and limited point relation

Tags: real-analysis

If some set is bounded. there must exist an limited point?

and if it is can you explain the detail?

The bounded somehow related with the limited point?

I''m trying to prove that  every compact set E is closed.

since I proved every compact set E is bounded.

and I assumed E is open. then every interior point p  $$p \in E $$

$$N\epsilon(p)  \cap E = \emptyset$$

but since E is bounded. There exist an limited point in E.(not sure) 
then contradiction....

Comment: A finite set is bounded and has no limit point. You should try to show that if $E$ is not closed, then $E$ has an open cover with no finite subcover. Are you working in $\Bbb R$? In $\Bbb R^n$?

Comment: working on R Not $R^n$

Answer (score 1):

HINT: Suppose that $E\subseteq\Bbb R$ is not closed; then there is a point $p\in\Bbb R\setminus E$ that is a limit point of $E$. For $n\in\Bbb Z^+$ let $$U_n=\left\{x\in\Bbb R:|x-p|>\frac1n\right\}\;,$$ and show that $\{U_n:n\in\Bbb Z^+\}$ is an open cover of $E$ with no finite subcover.

Comment: If the downvote was for the obvious typo ($\ge$ for $>$) in the original version, a comment would have been more useful both to me and to readers. If it was for some other reason, it *definitely* requires an explanation.

Comment: I'm out of upvotes for the day, but you're not alone in thinking that downvote is ridiculous.

Comment: @Potato: Thanks; I was wondering if I had a really bad blind spot here!

Comment: weird people. do not leave any explanation for down vote...